# Capybara with selenium fails. Works in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, selenium-webdriver

I have a simple login system that works in the browser. I recently switched my cucumber tests to use selenium because I need ajax calls and now the login/auth steps do not pass anymore. The app still functions normally in firefox and chromium.

Here are the Steps and the definitions

**features/authentication.features**

```
Feature: Require Authentication
  In order to restrict access to the app
  A User
  Must be logged in

  Scenario: Accessing Tracks   
    Given I am not logged in   
    And I visit the "Tracks" page   
    Then I should see the "Welcome" page 
    And I should see "You need to be logged in to access this page"

  Scenario: Accessing Tracks when Logged in 
    Given I am logged in      
    And I visit the "Tracks" page   
    Then I should see the "Tracks" page
```

**features/step_definitions/register_and_login_steps.rb**

```
When(/^I log in as "(.*?)"$/) do |name|
  create_and_login(name)
end

When(/^I log in$/) do          
  create_and_login('tester')   
end

When(/^I log out$/) do         
  visit(logout_path)
end   

When(/^I should be logged out$/) do
  page.should have_title "Welcome"
  page.should have_text "Please log in"
end   

When(/^I am( not)? logged in$/) do |negative|
  if negative
    visit(logout_path)
  else
    create_and_login('anyone') 
    page.should have_title 'Welcome'
  end
end
```

**features/step_definitions/should_see_steps.rb**

```
When(/I should( not)? see the "(.*?)" page$/) do |negative, page_title|
  if negative
    page.should_not have_title page_title
  else
    page.should have_title page_title
  end 
end

When(/^I should( not)? see "(.*?)"$/) do |negative, text|
  if negative
    page.should_not have_text text
  else
  page.should have_text text
  end 
end

When(/^I visit the "(.*?)" page$/) do |page|
  path = page.downcase + "_path"
  visit_path(path)
end
```

**features/support/helpers/user.rb**

```
def password_for(user)
  user + '_password_'
end

def create_user(name)
  return if User.exists?(name: name)
  user = User.create!(name: name,
  password: password_for(name),
  password_confirmation: password_for(name)) 
end

def create_and_login(name)
  create_user(name)
  visit(logout_path)
  visit(login_path)
  fill_in 'Name', with: name 
  fill_in 'Password', with: password_for(name)
  click_button 'Login'
end
```

**Gemfile** (test group only)

```
group :test do 
  gem 'guard-spork', '~> 1.5.0'
  gem 'rb-inotify', '~> 0.9.0' 
  gem 'spork', '~> 0.9.2'

  gem 'guard-rspec','~> 2.5.0'

  gem 'cucumber-rails' , '~> 1.3.0'
  gem 'database_cleaner','~> 0.9.1'
  gem 'guard-cucumber', '~> 1.3.2'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.1.0'   
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~>2.31.0'
end
```

log/test.log

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
   (0.3ms)  begin transaction
Started GET "/logout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-22 01:57:49 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#destroy as HTML
Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:42286/login
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-22 01:57:49 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (26.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_player.html.haml (0.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 64ms (Views: 63.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/assets/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-22 01:57:49 +0200
Served asset /application.js - 200 OK (8ms)
Started GET "/assets/application.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-22 01:57:49 +0200
Served asset /application.css - 200 OK (3ms)
Started GET "/tracks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-22 01:57:49 +0200
Processing by TracksController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."session" = '' LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:42286/login
Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 62ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-22 01:57:49 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (1.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_player.html.haml (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (1.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."name" = 'anyone' LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."name" = 'anyone' LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."session" IS NULL LIMIT 1
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `password_digest`
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `session`
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("admin", "created_at", "name", "password_digest", "session", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["admin", nil], ["created_at", Sun, 21 Apr 2013 23:57:49 UTC +00:00], ["name", "anyone"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$2kPN1wqnXI/G9b/1KMR2x.7yCHCaKwftE7PXm/q4u9Q9bcWCTenMG"], ["session", "91e2394dcdc86ada3836b258ad6bd2c850f99e03"], ["updated_at", Sun, 21 Apr 2013 23:57:49 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.0ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
Started GET "/logout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-22 01:57:49 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#destroy as HTML
Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:42286/login
Completed 302 Found in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-22 01:57:49 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (0.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_player.html.haml (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-22 01:57:50 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (0.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_player.html.haml (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 2.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started POST "/sessions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-22 01:57:50 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "session"=>{"name"=>"anyone", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."name" = 'anyone' LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:42286/login
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-22 01:57:50 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (0.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_player.html.haml (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/tracks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-22 01:57:50 +0200
Processing by TracksController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."session" = '' LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:42286/login
Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-22 01:57:50 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (27.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_player.html.haml (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 29ms (Views: 28.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: There is none, the test fails because the login does not work. The lines `Processing by TracksController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."session" = '' LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:42286/login` are suspicious. The session should be passed correctly but it's not for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix was to not set selenium as the default capybara driver and tag the tests that require ajax with @javascript.

Comment: I've run into a similar situation; some AJAX code works in browser but Capybara specs fail, when using either PhantomJS or Selenium driver. I'd love to know more about how you solved your problem. Could you elaborate on this more? Are you saying that the tests were breaking *because* Selenium was the default driver?